# Regex inside PHP. Tighter capturing rules

Tags: php, regex

I'm practicing Regex and I'm quite bad at it at the moment.

I basically want to strip the span out the string using regex. the data tag is of an unknown size prior to this.

```
<span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="*@jish*">
usertagslug[jishstaff]
usertagname[JishStaff]
</span>‍ lol try do a
<span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at- query="*@jish*">usertagslug[jishstaff] usertagname[JishStaff]
</span>‍"
```

Here's my PHP class with the regex in there:

```
{
protected $value;


public function stripAll($value)
{
    $value = preg_replace('/data-atwho-at-query="@(.*)">/', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace('<span class="atwho-inserted"', '', $value);
    $value = str_replace('</span>', '', $value);

    return $value;
}

}
```

The result I get currently basically leaves me with:

```
usertagslug[jishstaff] usertagname[JishStaff]‍
```

as apposed to the expected output of

```
usertagslug[jishstaff] usertagname[JishStaff]‍ lol try do a usertagslug[jishstaff] usertagname[JishStaff]‍
```

I'm just unsure on how to be stricter with my regex.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the span elements by replacing all occurences of `<\/?span[^>]*>` with an empty string.

After that you'll be left with

```
usertagslug[jishstaff]
usertagname[JishStaff]
‍ lol try do a
usertagslug[jishstaff] usertagname[JishStaff]
```

Then perform a trim on each line and replace all `\n` with a space.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand that piece of regex too much but it's damn powerful!